# Can you override the formatter for a specific log in log.properties

Tags: java, configuration, logging

I am using log.properties to configure logging for a Java app. Each class gets its own logger named after itself (e.g. com.company.program.ClassX).

I want to set a custom formatter for just one log, and leave the handler with the SimpleFormatter. Is this possible?

I am not interested in using log4j or another of the other logging suites. I am well aware of them. Nor am I interested in configuring a customer formatter for the logger through code, although if that is the only way to do it, it would be nice to know. Google isn't helping, and I am having problems testing this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Handler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) owns the Formatter, not the Logger. You would need a second Handler to perform special formatting. I'm assuming that you want both to show up in the console, so the answer would appear to be "no".

Something to try:
Create a subclass of java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler and use it as a second console handler. (I'm assuming here that you're using the [system property](http://edocs.bea.com/kodo/docs303/ref_guide_logging_jdk14.html), otherwise it won't help you.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a limitation of Java logging.

You should decide to become interested in log4j.  java.util.logging is only marginally better than `System.out.println`